# Horizontal pagination in Table

Tags: material-ui, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am evaluating [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) and [material-ui-react](https://material-ui.com/) libraries for rendering a complex, editable table in my React project. One of the requirements is that when the table size is more than horizontal viewport of the page, some area to the right should be pinned and the user should be able to navigate to other columns using left/right arrow buttons displayed on top edges of the pinned area. The styling of pinned columns and arrows should also be customizable.

Is this possible in ag-grid or material-ui-react?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievable in ag-grid. Take a look at [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pinning/#example-column-pinning) example on the documentation page of ag-grid.

As for the extra features you would like ("when the table size is more than horizontal viewport of the page", "styling of pinned columns and arrows should also be customizable" etc.) these are also possible with ag-grid, but they don't come out-of-the-box; you will have to implement this yourself.

Comment: Can you give the link in docs where this feature ("when the table size is more than horizontal viewport of the page, some area to the right should be pinned and the user should be able to navigate to other columns using left/right arrow buttons") is mentioned? I couldn't find it in docs..